handle exception thrown by inner function in Unit test using xUnit
XML Parsing function is as follows:
public async void ParseXML(XMLReader reader)
{
   if(await reader.ReadAsync() && reader.Name == "Node1")
   {
    while(await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
           if(reader.Name == "SubNode")
           {
               await ParseSubNode(reader.ReadSubtree());
               reader.Skip()
           }
        }       
    }
  }
}

Now assume ParseSubNode() function is throwing FormatException.
How to handle this exception in Unit test written using xUnit, NSubstitute ,  and Shouldly ?

It may matter if you want it to fail (so input is correct, throwing the exception is not), or to pass (input is incorrect, and you actually want to verify that the exception gets thrown).
